# Reuse old long-lived Instagram user access access token after refreshing it

Tags: php, token, refresh, instagram-api

I know you can refresh a long-lived Instagram User Access token that is still valid by using:

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token
    ?grant_type=ig_refresh_token
    &access_token={long-lived-access-token}
```

However, the response provides a new access token. I have tried to use the old access token after using the refresh call and it seems to work. My question is, does the old refresh token also get updated with the new expiration time or would it expire on its original expiry time. I would like to not have to update the token every time so that I can schedule a job which just refreshes the token but doesn't update it with the new value everywhere. I have gone through the documentation and several topics related to it but can't find an answer to if the old token gets refreshed too. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

When you refresh a long-lived Instagram User Access token using the API endpoint you mentioned, a new access token is provided in the response. While it's true that the old access token can still be used, it doesn't necessarily mean that the old refresh token will remain valid for the same amount of time.

The old refresh token may expire at its original expiry time and may not be updated with the new expiration time. So, it's important to always refresh your access token when using it to ensure that all systems using the token continue to function correctly.

Additionally, refreshing your token before it expires can help ensure its validity and prevent any interruptions.

In conclusion, it's best to refresh your access token when it's needed for the most secure and accurate approach. Always using a current access token in your operations will guarantee a smooth experience and security.